# What software/theme is running on this website?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, theme

See http://www.anscamobile.com

I like the design of this website, and would like to know if you guys can identify a similar design/theme/CMS setup that is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

The blog is Wordpress. Everything else looks custom but I can't 100% sure.

Comment: Custom w/use of [Blueprint CSS framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) (from looking at the `print.css` import)